# Как правильно написать цепочку промисов

Tags: javascript

Изучаю промисы нашла не сложный пример хочу его решить но пока у меня не получается  Условие такое:нужно написать функцию toggleUserState(ms), которая возвращает промис, переходящий в состояние "resolved" через ms миллисекунд. Значением исполнившегося промиса должно быть то кол-во миллисекунд которое передали во время вызова функции toggleUserState.

```js
const toggleUserState = ms => {
  // Твой код
};

const logger = time => console.log(`Resolved after ${time}ms`);

// Вызовы функции для проверки
toggleUserState(2000).then(logger); 
toggleUserState(1000).then(logger); 
toggleUserState(1500).then(logger);
```

Я внутри этой функции создаю промис и возвращаю resolve но не могу понять что сделать с time? Вот мой код

```js
const toggleUserState = ms => {
  // Твой код
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(logger);
    }, 2000);
  });
};

const logger = time => console.log(`Resolved after ${time}ms`);

// Вызовы функции для проверки
toggleUserState(2000).then(logger); 
toggleUserState(1000).then(logger); 
toggleUserState(1500).then(logger);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

То, что вы передаете в функцию `resolve` и будет результатом промиса, а у вас сейчас там `logger` передается зачем-то + у вас функция всегда через 2 секунды будет отрабатывать, ибо у вас значение для таймаута захардкожено

```js
const toggleUserState = ms => {
  // Твой код
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(ms); // То что передали в resolve, то вернется из промиса
    }, ms);
  });
};

const logger = time => console.log(`Resolved after ${time}ms`);

// Вызовы функции для проверки
toggleUserState(2000).then(logger);
toggleUserState(1000).then(logger);
toggleUserState(1500).then(logger);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое что откликнулись я это сразу поняла после того как задала вопрос) таймаут я дописала сама. Отблагодарила)

Comment: @zarina можете выбрать ответ, как правильный ( галочка внизу рейтинга ), вот это будет благодарность:D

Comment: @zarina либо свой, что бы другие пользователи сразу видели, какой ответ решает вопрос

Comment: Хорошо) Буду дальше изучать промиси довольно интересная вещь)

Answer (score 0):

```js
const toggleUserState = ms => {
  // Твой код
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(ms);
    }, 2000);
  });
};

const logger = time => console.log(`Resolved after ${time}ms`);

// Вызовы функции для проверки
toggleUserState(2000).then(logger); 
toggleUserState(1000).then(logger); 
toggleUserState(1500).then(logger);
```

Получается, что нужно было написать суда чтобы найти ответ. Нужно было вызвать правильную функцию чтоб все заработало! Но если у кого то будут еще варианты буду очень рада их увидить.

Comment: _которая возвращает промис, переходящий в состояние "resolved" через ms миллисекунд_ у вас всегда через 2секунды будет резолвиться

Comment: Я поняла, уберу.